# Images show up as html mime gibberish - PHP - Glide

Tags: php, image, server, php-glide

So I'm using the Glide (thephpleague) image manipulations system to create thumbnails on a site. When I use small thumbnails like http://dramaguru.net/images/titles/mohabbat_tum_se_nafrat_hai_147.jpeg?h=74&w=75 it shows up as html mime gibberish but the same image larger thumbnail shows up fine.

Large thumbnail: http://dramaguru.net/images/titles/mohabbat_tum_se_nafrat_hai_147.jpeg?h=174&w=175

Is this my server config, or a code issue? Any ideas?

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a content-type header `header('content-type: image/jpeg')`, but without seeing any code, I can't be sure.

Also, the small image has two expires headers and 3 cache-control headers (inspect the network request using chrome for example).

Comment: The odd thing is for large thumbnails it's fine and gives the proper content type, no? If the content type was set to something or missing something wouldn't it missing across all thumbnail sizes?

Comment: Please share your code, the smaller image doesn't set the content-type properly. Inspect the headers being sent and you will see that the larger image sets the content-type to text-html.

Comment: You might also want to turn on error logging, I have a feeling that somehow the content-type header is overwritten because of a PHP error (possibly an exif error)